How to Change Umi RPC endpoint
After initializing an umi instance with an RPC endpoint how do I change this RPC endpoint to a new one?
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";

const umi = createUmi(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));


This is possible using the web3JsRpc plugin from @metaplex-foundation/umi-rpc-web3js plugin.
import { web3JsRpc } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-rpc-web3js";

umi.use(web3JsRpc(new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"))));

ref: https://developers.metaplex.com/umi/rpc#configuring-the-rpcs-endpoint
